# Merge two Laravel collections elements and replace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have this laravel collection called **$box_items**.

```
Collection {#320 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "img_alt" => "<span>Original</span> gifts"
      "class" => "personalised-gifts"
      "elements" => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:2 [▼
          "id" => 2638
          "type" => "ARTICLE"
        ]
        1 => array:2 [▼
          "id" => 2100
          "type" => "ARTICLE"
        ]
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:5 [▼
      "img_alt" => "<span>Love</span> gifts"
      "class" => "love-gifts"
      "elements" => array:3 [▼
        0 => array:2 [▼
          "id" => 1072
          "type" => "CATEGORY"
        ]
        1 => array:2 [▼
          "id" => 6186
          "type" => "ARTICLE"
        ]
        2 => array:2 [▼
          "id" => 1028
          "type" => "CATEGORY"
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

On the other hand, I have another collection called **$elements**, this **$elements** collection have extra information about the 'element' field in the **$box_items** collection.

This is my **$elements** collection:

```
array:5 [▼
   0 => {#313 ▼
      +"type": "ARTICLE"
      +"name": "Ceramic Mug"
      +"resource_id": "2638"
      +"seo": {#314 ▶}
  }

  1 => {#323 ▼
    +"type": "CATEGORY"
    +"name": "Personalised Blankets"
    +"category": {#325 ▼
      +"id": 1072
      +"gallery_id": null
      +"final": true
    }
    +"seo": {#326 ▶}
  }

  2 => {#327 ▼
      +"type": "ARTICLE"
      +"name": "Circle Cushion"
      +"resource_id": "2100"
      +"seo": {#328 ▶}
  }

  3 => {#329 ▼
      +"type": "ARTICLE"
      +"name": "Book"
      +"resource_id": "6186"
      +"seo": {#330 ▶}
  }

  4 => {#341 ▼
    +"type": "CATEGORY"
    +"name": "Gifts for men"
    +"category": {#342 ▼
      +"id": 1028
      +"gallery_id": null
      +"final": false
    }
    +"seo": {#343 ▶}
  }

]
```

I want replace the **$elements** CATEGORIES and ARTICLES by the **$box_items** elements field.

I want this final result:

```
Collection {#320 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "img_alt" => "<span>Original</span> gifts"
      "class" => "personalised-gifts"
      "elements" => array:2 [▼
        0 => {#313 ▼
            +"type": "ARTICLE"
            +"name": "Ceramic Mug"
            +"resource_id": "2638"
            +"seo": {#314 ▶}
        }
        2 => {#327 ▼
            +"type": "ARTICLE"
            +"name": "Circle Cushion"
            +"resource_id": "2100"
            +"seo": {#328 ▶}
        }
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:5 [▼
      "img_alt" => "<span>Love</span> gifts"
      "class" => "love-gifts"
      "elements" => array:3 [▼
         0 => {#323 ▼
          +"type": "CATEGORY"
          +"name": "Personalised Blankets"
          +"category": {#325 ▼
            +"id": 1072
            +"gallery_id": null
            +"final": true
          }
          +"seo": {#326 ▶}
        }
        1 => {#329 ▼
            +"type": "ARTICLE"
            +"name": "Book"
            +"resource_id": "6186"
            +"seo": {#330 ▶}
        }
        2 => {#341 ▼
          +"type": "CATEGORY"
          +"name": "Gifts for men"
          +"category": {#342 ▼
            +"id": 1028
            +"gallery_id": null
            +"final": false
          }
          +"seo": {#343 ▶}
        }
      ]
    ]
```

EDIT: error in the line if($article_element['id'] == $extra_element->category->id);

```
foreach($articles_rows as &$article)
        {

           foreach($article['elements'] as &$article_element)
           {

              foreach($cats_and_arts as $extra_element)
              {

                if($extra_element->type == 'CATEGORY')
                {

                    if($article_element['id'] == $extra_element->category->id)//Undefined index: id
                    {

                         $article_element = (array)$extra_element;
                    }
                }

                if($extra_element->type == 'ARTICLE')
                {

                    if($article_element['id'] == $extra_element->article->id)
                    {

                         $article_element = (array)$extra_element;

                    }
                }

              }
           }
         }
            dd($articles_rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. It should work for you.

```
foreach($box_items as &$box){
   foreach($box["elements"] as &$box_element){
      foreach($elements as $element){
         if($box_element->id == $element->id){
            $box_element = $element;
         }
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: But where can I store all the information?, like the final result

Comment: it will be available in $box_items the items are passed by references dd($box_items) to see the update

Comment: Ok, this return me this error: "Attempt to modify property of non-object", because the field elements contains arrays not object...

Comment: please what variable is been refered to non-object

Comment: In the line  foreach($box->elements as &$box_element){

Comment: I edit the main post, the only problem is the last line that return me //Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Mmm when the loop iterate one time, I retrieve the error Undefined index: id in the line if($article_element['id'] == $extra_element->category->id)

Comment: Not work all the code, you can check my edit in the main post